# How to find a Chain of Messages (Hierarchical queries in MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a message table with these constraints:

```
-Each message have their own ID. 
-Each message belongs to a message type.
-Each message can be a child of other message. 
-A parent message can be a parent of different type of messages.
-The depth of hierarchy is unknown.
```

```
+--------------+---------------+-------------+------------------+
| messageText  |  messageType  |  messageID  |  parentMessageID |
+--------------+---------------+-------------+------------------+
| msg text 1   |  1            |  1          |  NULL            |
| msg text 2   |  1            |  2          |  1               |
| msg text 3   |  1            |  3          |  8               |
| msg text 4   |  2            |  4          |  1               |
| msg text 5   |  2            |  5          |  2               |
| msg text 6   |  2            |  6          |  1               |
| msg text 7   |  3            |  7          |  5               |
| msg text 8   |  3            |  8          |  NULL            |
| msg text 9   |  1            |  9          |  8               |
+--------------+---------------+-------------+------------------+
```

```
Extra Constraint: 
-There is no such case that "1 child belongs to many parents". 
That is each message must belongs to Just 1 parent or belongs to NO parent (ie parentMessageID is NULL)

-Parent child relationship doesn't go to the right order from top down. 
Ex, look at the above table, messageID "3" is a child of the below messageID "8".
```

-**Requirement 1**: user provides a messageID & the system should find all of the ancestors of that messages.

Ex1: user searches for messageID "7" & it should print out:

```
+--------------+---------------+-------------+------------------+
| messageText  |  messageType  |  messageID  |  parentMessageID |
+--------------+---------------+-------------+------------------+
| msg text 1   |  1            |  1          |  NULL            |
| msg text 2   |  1            |  2          |  1               |
| msg text 5   |  2            |  5          |  2               |
| msg text 7   |  3            |  7          |  5               |
+--------------+---------------+-------------+------------------+
```

Ex3: user searches for messageID "3" & it should print out:

```
+--------------+---------------+-------------+------------------+
| messageText  |  messageType  |  messageID  |  parentMessageID |
+--------------+---------------+-------------+------------------+
| msg text 8   |  3            |  8          |  NULL            |
| msg text 3   |  1            |  3          |  8               |
+--------------+---------------+-------------+------------------+
```

Note: in the ex1 & ex2. it should print out in the correct order start from VERY top to the VERY last order.

-**Requirement 2**: user provides a messageID & the system should find all of the descendants of that messages.

Ex1, user searches for messageID "8", then it should print out:

```
+--------------+---------------+-------------+------------------+
| messageText  |  messageType  |  messageID  |  parentMessageID |
+--------------+---------------+-------------+------------------+
| msg text 8   |  3            |  8          |  NULL            |
| msg text 3   |  1            |  3          |  8               |
| msg text 9   |  1            |  9          |  8               |
+--------------+---------------+-------------+------------------+
```

Ex2, user searches for messageID "2", it should print out:

```
+--------------+---------------+-------------+------------------+
| messageText  |  messageType  |  messageID  |  parentMessageID |
+--------------+---------------+-------------+------------------+
| msg text 2   |  1            |  2          |  1               |
| msg text 5   |  2            |  5          |  2               |
| msg text 7   |  3            |  7          |  5               |
+--------------+---------------+-------------+------------------+
```

I heard we can use session variable in Mysql but session variable just goes from top to down & thus doesn't give correct result. For ex, for the requirement2, we can do like this:

```
select messageText, messageType, @pv:=parentMessageID as 'parentMessageID' from table1
join
(select @pv:=2)tmp
where messageID=@pv
```

Someone provided this solution but i don't know if it can apply for my case.

```
 http://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/
```

so what is the best way to to find a Chain of Ancestor/Descendent Messages in Mysql?

Comment: With MySQL's limited SQL capabilities your only option is to write a stored procedure or using code in your application.

Comment: u means this solution http://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/

Comment: use the nested set model